# undefined Error getting data from object in javascript while using dot notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

I want to iterate through an array with object elements such as;

```
var location = [
    { continent: 'Africa',  country: 'Nigeria', population: 200 },
    { continent: 'Europe', country: 'Germany', population: 120 },
    { continent: 'Europe', country: 'Spain',  population: 100  },
    { continent: 'Asia', country: 'China', population: 500 },
    { continent: 'Africa',  country: 'Kenya', population: 70 },
    { continent: 'Europe', country: 'Poland',  population: 90 },
  ];
```

The aim is to get an output such as this:

```
{
  Africa: [ 'Nigeria', 'Kenya' ],
  Europe: [ 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Poland' ],
  Asia: [ 'China' ]
}
```

My challenge now is that when I use either dot or bracket notation to get the data with reference to the array, I keep getting undefined error. See code below:

```
var output = {};
for (let i = 0; i < location.length; i++){
    //var cont = location[i].country;
    //var fName = location[i].continent;
    
    if (output.hasOwnProperty(location[i].continent)){        
        output.location[i][continent].push(location[i].country);
    }else{
        output.location[i][continent] = [];
        output.location[i].continent.push(location[i].country);
    }

}
console.log(output);
```

Error:

[image]

When I declare them as variable it worked perfectly. See code below:

```
var output = {};
for (let i = 0; i < location.length; i++){
    var cont = location[i].country;
    var fName = location[i].continent;
    
    if (output.hasOwnProperty(location[i].continent)){        
        output[fName].push(cont);
    }else{
        output[fName] = [];
        output[fName].push(cont);

    }

}
console.log(output);
```

I want to understand why the first code won't work.

I tried using dot and bracket notation which I believed should give me the output without error.

Comment: You need `output[location[i].continent]`, not `output.location[i].continent`.

Comment: I see I have to combine both dot and bracket notation. Because when I used  `itemData[i][itemName]`  I got the same error but when I changed it to `itemData[i].itemName` I got the desired output.

Comment: You need to be aware that `x.y` is equivalent to `x["y"]`!